# $http calculate download time

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this function which calculates the time it takes to download a text file (3MB in size) from my server. It works fine for just one request but if I try to run say, 10 of these at once the time the call spend waiting for a response from the server is included in loadTime. Is there any way I can get a trigger when the actual download starts?

Here is my function

```
function getLargeData() {
    var loadTime = 0;
    var dlSpeed = 0;
    var promise = $q.defer();
    var startTime = new Date();
    $networkSvc.getLargeData()
        .success(function (data) {
            loadTime = new Date() - startTime;
            dlSpeed = 3 / (loadTime / 1000);
            var ret = { loadTime: loadTime, dlSpeed: dlSpeed };
            promise.resolve(ret);
            return promise.promise;
        })
        .error(function() {
            $scope.message = "Error - could not contact server.";
        });
    return promise.promise;
}
```

Comment: not really without polling server in another series of repeated requests  and having download script doing a session update during it's processing. Alternative might be socket connections

Answer (score 0):

The promise **then** can have third argument, which is notification function that can be notified from deferred object, before finish.

```
.then(   function() {  
$log.log('success');  },  
null,
 $log.log );
```

And there is possible function to resolve.

```
   function resolveProgress() {  
    for (var i=0; i<=10; i++) {  
    deferred.notify(i);
    if (i>=100) { deferred.resolve() };  
    }; }
```